# Create a coordinate grid against a coordinate (Lat, long) & compare the averaged value of a metric that lie within this grid from coordinates of file2

Tags: python, pandas, coordinates, geospatial, geopandas

I have 2 files, each having 3 columns- Latitude, Longitude & Value. These 2 files contain coordinates that may be very close but not exactly equal Hence one to one comparison cannot be done. So, Ideal way as per my understanding should be to create a dummy rectangular or polygon boundary against each coordinate with say 10 x 10m and compare value of all coordinates that lie within this boundary from the other file.

I don't need to show anything on map or charts. I just need simple tabular comparison.

I tried doing below. This groups the coordinates in 1 file and same can be done for 2nd file but again,the grouped values are not same hence I cannot compare both the files with this method.

```
   step = 0.0002
    to_bin = lambda x: np.floor(x / step) * step
    df_temp["latBin"] = to_bin(df_temp.Latitude)
    df_temp["lonBin"] = to_bin(df_temp.Longitude)
    groups = df.groupby(["latBin", "lonBin"])
```

`
Then I tried below method by converting from coordinates to x,y system but still the same issue.

```
  def apply_fun (raw):
    x,y,_,_ = utm.from_latlon(raw['Latitude'],raw['Longitude']) 
    return str(np.round(x/20))+"|"+str(np.round(y/20))


    x = df_temp.apply(lambda row : apply_fun(row),axis=1)
    df_temp.insert(3,'Group',x)

    gdf = df_temp.groupby(['Group']).agg({"Latitude":["mean"],"Longitude":["mean","count"],"thp":   ["mean"]})
    gdf = gdf.reset_index().drop(columns=['Group'],level=0)
    gdf.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in gdf.columns]`
```

My Objective is to basically GROUP all coordinates in file 1 that lie in 10x10 metres boundary and compare coordinates from file 2 that lie within this boundary against each coordinate of file 1.

Hope I am clear what is needed.

Need your guidance and support here please, thanks